How can the microphone senstivity be improved? It works for only a few centimeters
I am using an electret microphone with the preamplifier circuit attached below.  The problem is that the microphone works only when I speak very closely to the microphone.  If I speak from a distance, the  microphone does not work well above 10cm range.


This circuit has no voltage amplification if you take the signal from the emitter. At the collector you can pick up an amplified signal.

Is the microphone a noise canceling design? Noise canceling designs require having the mic nearly touching the lips.

no its gooseneck mic for long range audio signal capturing.

This amplifier (emitter follower) has a gain of 1. Clearly not enough.
Using the common emitter configuration, suggested in the diagram, will provide more amplification.
The circuit shown will provide a gain of 10, approximately R1/R5. Decreasing R5 to 22 ohms will increase the gain to 100. The low frequency (dc) gain is 2.2. Choose C2 for the low frequency corner frequency. Too small will reduce base response.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

does my mic works if i speak from 1 meter distance and what is the capacitance value of above circuit

The circuit is the same as before. I modified only the capacitance leg of the emitter circuit and moved the output to the collector through a coupling capacitor, The modifications are suggestions. Experiment with the values to see if it will work to your satisfaction.

it works only when i speak very close to mic.

Please edit the question to show the rest of the system.

ok tell me a one thing if i give my mic input through a preamp to spk does it work properly if  not then suggest me a circuit in which my mic input can go directly to a spk through a preamp and it work proper.
